# A change in the BigQuery behaviour of TRUNCATE with streaming buffer

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting an error when trying to truncate a table with an active streaming buffer while until 23.2.2024 it worked fine.

> googleapi: Error 400: TRUNCATE DML statement over table XXX would
> affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported,
> invalidQuery

We have daily tests running for a while now that truncate a table with a streaming buffer and they always worked but started failing on 23.2.2024 without any code change on our end.

I didn't find any documentation for this change, only the fact that it seems the docs were updated on 23.2.2024 and the [TRUNCATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#truncate_table_statement) statement now appears to be a DML statement.

From an older Google Cloud blog [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/bigquery-explained-data-manipulation-dml), it clearly says it's a DDL statement.

> The TRUNCATE TABLE statement is a DDL (Data Definition Language)
> operation that removes all rows from a table but leaves the table
> metadata intact

Since it is undocumented, I'm wondering if anyone else can add some details on the change.

Comment: You may have uncovered some kind of bug.  You might want to open a ticket with Google.

Comment: Google issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326622789